# grunt connect proxy : proxy created but i get a 404

Tags: angularjs, proxy

I have currently a simple angular application configured with yeoman, and the only customisation I'm trying is with grunt-connect-proxy. So I followed the instructions and modified my Gruntfile :

```
var proxySnippet = require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest;
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    ...
    grunt.initConfig({
        ...
        connect: {
            ...
            server: {
                proxies: [
                {
                     context: '/api',
                     host: 'somevirtualhost',
                     port: 8080,
                     https: false,
                     changeOrigin: true
                }
                ]
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            proxySnippet,
                            ...
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            ...
        },
    });
    ...
    grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
        ...
        grunt.task.run([
            ...
            'configureProxies:server',
            ...
        ]);
    });
}
```

And in a controller I tried the following :

```
var Versions = $resource('/api/version/:versId', { versId: '@id' });
var version = Versions.get({ versId: 'Ultra' }, function () {
    console.log('here I am');
});
```

When I run grunt serve I can see the proxy is created :

```
Running "configureProxies:server" (configureProxies) task
Proxy created for: /api to somevirtualhost:8080
```

But in the console of the web page I get :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:9000/api/version/Ultra
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some clues here : https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy/issues/69
I don't understand everything but for now I add the headers option in my proxies :

```
proxies: [
          {
              context: '/api',
              host: 'somevirtualhost',
              port: 8080,
              https: false,
              changeOrigin: true,
              headers: {
                  'host': 'somevirtualhost'
              },
          }
        ]
```

And it seems to work